# Margin or Padding Shorthand in React Native

Tags: css, react-native

How to define margin/padding shorthand in React Native?

```
margin: 10px 20px;
```

Comment: Oddly, the docs say that it supports a String (https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#margin) and even references the MDN listing (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) where you can pass in a String like `margin: 10px 50px 20px 0;` but it doesn't work for me and, in fact, it crashes my Android runtime when I try to use it.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter React Native docs suck, so no surprise here. They are often wrong or unclear.

Comment: @RoboRobok No argument there. :)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

When using plain React Native styles you can rewrite your css above to

```
{
  marginVertical: 10,
  marginHorizontal: 20
}
```

Otherwise the above syntax can be achieved if you're using something like [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com), which uses [css-to-react-native](https://github.com/styled-components/css-to-react-native) under the hood.

Answer (score 14):

I created this helper function in a past project:

```
const getShortHand = (style: string, ...values: Array<number | string>) => {
  if (values.length === 1) {
    return { [style]: values[0] }
  }
  const _genCss = (...values: Array<number | string | undefined>) => ({
    [style + 'Top']: values[0],
    [style + 'Right']: values[1],
    [style + 'Bottom']: values[2],
    [style + 'Left']: values[3],
  })
  if (values.length === 2) {
    return _genCss(values[0], values[1], values[0], values[1])
  }
  if (values.length === 3) {
    return _genCss(values[0], values[1], values[2], values[1])
  }
  return _genCss(values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3])
}

export const padding = (...values: Array<number | string>) => getShortHand('padding', ...values)
export const margin = (...values: Array<number | string>) => getShortHand('margin', ...values)
```

The usage is similar with the normal css shorthand:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    ...padding(12, 20),
  },
}
```